# Image sliding hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using  this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2L1kb4r5/6/) but i want more than one images sliding with hover effect,this link only shows one image slide i want more than one image to slide on it.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="fimg"><a href="#"><img height="130px" width="100%" src="a.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div> <div class="simg"> 
<a href="#"><img height="130px" width="100%" src="A.jpg" alt="" /><p class="text_over_image" style="font-size:36px;">TEXT</p></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#container").hover(function(){
        $("img", this).stop().animate({top:"-130px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
    }, function() {
        $("img", this).stop().animate({top:"0px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
    });
});
```

Comment: You want more than image to replicate that effect when **only** one of the images is hovered?

Comment: @theblindprophet yea when hove on it only one image is swap i need more than one images slide

Comment: I can create an answer of this if it is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/2L1kb4r5/137/

Comment: @theblindprophet i want more than one image slide on the same container

Comment: Ahhh, but this would slide past images that aren't the first and the last. Or do you want to hover once and it slides one, then hover again, and it slides to the next?

Comment: @darthrubens i want more images to slide on the same container as you see when hove only one image is slide i want more images to slide on it one by one

Comment: @theblindprophet one one time hover and it shows more than one images slide one by one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108657/discussion-between-asad-ali-and-theblindprophet).

Comment: I have update it so that you can skip all the ones in between, https://jsfiddle.net/2L1kb4r5/139/. Is this what you needed?

Comment: @AdityaSingh no you just chnage the image i want more images to slide like this with hover.is this possible?

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by ` i want more images to slide like this with hover`. What is the exact expectation on hover? How many images you want to slide?

Comment: @AdityaSingh as you can see when hove one image is slide i want many image slide when hover on it.is this clear?